# Why am I getting an "Invalid json" error for my title command in 15w35e?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Upon running

```
/title hacatu title {text:"test"}
```

I am given the error message "Invalid json: malformed JSON at line 1 column 3". I have never used the tellraw command before when creating command block contraptions, so I don't really know what I am doing wrong. I have already run the command `/title hacatu times 40 100 40`, which ran perfectly fine.

Comment: This probably isn't a snapshot issue

Comment: Probably not. I didn't notice my title was so indisctriptive :P

Comment: I changed the title now.

Comment: You might find this title generator useful: http://www.dragnoz.com/minecraft-title-generator/

Comment: Thanks, but even copying and pasting those commands doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the snapshots JSON no longer uses lenient parsing, thus you need to put quotation marks around every string:

```
/title hacatu title {"text":"test"}
```

Answer (score -1):

These might all be super outdated by now, even if they were posted when minecraft 1.9 came out, because 1.10 may have changed up the command severely, but now 1.10.1 may have glitched it so it doesn't work at all.

Comment: this answer is better. i posted twice.